# AWS ELB access logs not showing 5XX errors

Tags: elastic-load-balancer

I am seeing ELB_Code_5XX alarms in Cloudwatch but I am not able to see any errors logged in ELB access logs.

I have used the Standard AWS Template to configure ELB access logs. Am i missing on something in the configuration?